# Rear lights on 2012 Nissan Rogue

Tags: nissan, tail-lights, rogue

I am trying to help a friend solve a mystery:  At various times her taillights and rear upper bar light stay on after shutting down the engine.  This can happen day or night -  i.e., the lights don't have to be on first.   She also goes through taillight bulbs on one side pretty quickly.  Any ideas before I start tracing the wiring?

Comment: How long do the lights remain on? The upper bar light is actuated by the brake pedal. Do the lights go off if the brake pedal is lifted by one's toe?

Answer (score 4):

As @fred_dot_u said, test to see if the lights will go off if you raise the brake pedal up with your hand/foot. If so, it's likely that your brake pedal switch needs to be adjusted, or less likely it is defective.

Adjust your brake pedal switch.

https://www.yourmechanic.com/article/how-to-replace-your-brake-light-switch-by-spencer-cates

Making an free account at www.AutoZone.com will allow you access to repair guides specifically for your vehicle. They might have clearer, more targeted, information regarding adjusting your brake light switch.

It also seems it might be related to a Recall of the switches on Pathfinders of that era. I would call a local dealer and ask if they can check for Recalls by your VIN, just be to sure.

https://nissan.oemdtc.com/103/pc464-stop-lamp-switch-adjustment-2013-2014-nissan-pathfinder

I hope this helps.